# Error While Editing Arrays

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm working with Arrays and trying to change the text value of an array to numerical for an easier evaluation as the code progress. I seem to be having issues with Arrays, but I'm not sure why. Can you take a look at my code and offer feedback?

```
Dim MonthlyValuesUnclean() As Range
Dim CodeCountOne As Long

Range("A1").Select
CodeCountOne = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) 'Counts Total Number of Codes Before Clean
ReDim MonthlyValuesUnclean(CodeCountOne, 1 To 3)

For columnNumber = 1 To 3
    ReDim MonthlyValuesUnclean(CodeCountOne, columnNumber)
    For counter = 1 To CodeCountOne

        If MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Text = "R" Then
            MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Value = 5
        ElseIf MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Text = "Y" Then
            MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Value = 4
        ElseIf MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Text = "G" Then
            MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Value = 3
        ElseIf MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Text = "?" Then
            MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Value = 2
        Else
            MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber).Value = 1
        End If

    Next counter
Next columnNumber
```

Comment: It would help if you told us what the problem is...

Comment: Also, a better explanation of what you're attempting to do would help. I think you are probably going about this the wrong way, but without knowing your intentions, it is difficult to suggest a better method.

Comment: `Dim MonthlyValuesUnclean() As Range` <-- this establishes an Array of Range objects. I doubt that is what you actually want.  Further, you never actually assign anything *to* this array, and then you try to iterate its contents, this will not work. Also, array elements don't have a `.Text` property, ec.

Comment: My apologies. What I am trying to do is take a range of cells and put them into the array. They are in columns B to D and there are "CodeCountOne" rows. The cells have either a "R" , "Y", "G", "?", " " character in them. I am hoping to loop through each cell in column B and change the text to a numerical value. Then move to column C and do the same. Then to Column D and do the same.

Answer (score 1):

*What I am trying to do is take a range of cells and put them into the array.*

OK, that's what I thought, but you haven't actually done that. You've defined an array of range objects (not what you want) and you have dimensioned that array probably correctly (but unnecessarily).

In this, we will first define and assign a range variable (`monthlyValuesRange`).  Then, we will assign the range's `.Value` array to an array variable (`MonthlyValuesUnclean`).  Then, we can process that array, and finally put those values back in to the worksheet.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim MonthlyValuesUnclean As Variant
    Dim CodeCountOne As Long
    Dim monthlyValuesRange As Range

    CodeCountOne = Application.CountA(Range("A:A")) 'Counts Total Number of Codes Before Clean

    'Define your range variable
    Set monthlyValuesRange = Range("A1:C" & CodeCountOne)

    'Assigns the range's value array to the MonthlyValuesUnclean array variable:
    MonthlyValuesUnclean = monthlyValuesRange.Value

    For columnNumber = 1 To 3
        For counter = 1 To CodeCountOne
        '## I find Select statement easier to work with:
        Select Case UCase(MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber))
            Case "R"
                MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber) = 5

            Case "Y"
                MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber) = 4

            Case "G"
                MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber) = 3

            Case "?"
                MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber) = 2

            Case Else
                MonthlyValuesUnclean(counter, columnNumber) = 1
         End Select
        Next counter
    Next columnNumber

    'Now put the updated values in the worksheet
     monthlyValuesRange.Value = MonthlyValuesUnclean
End Sub
```

Tested & confirmed this is working as expected.  Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

And an example of examining the `MonthlyValuesUnclean` in the VBE's locals window:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. However now the conent in cells A-C are being removed and no values are being stored. I'm not sure why this is occuring.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line before `End Sub` and examine the values held in the `monthlyValuesUnclean` variable in the VBE Locals window.  You will need to learn how to debug code, because I have tested this and it works.

Comment: If you have had a chance to try and debug, let me know if you're having problems with that. Cheers